# wooommerce add to cart based on gravity form radio button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, gravityforms

I have a WooCommerce gravity form that a user can choose a package based on radio button selection to signup. I want to add to cart a woocommerce product based on the selection. Below is the html and js of the radio button group but its not triggering:

```
<script>
    $('#choice_1_112_0').click(function() {
     window.location.href = 'www.domian.com/?add-to-cart=125';
     return false;
    });
</script>

<ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_1_112">
    <li class="gchoice_1_112_0">
    <input name="input_112" type="radio" value="Normal Package" id="choice_1_112_0">
    <label for="choice_1_112_0" id="label_1_112_0">Normal Package</label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_1_112_1">
        <input name="input_112" type="radio" value="eTrade Package" id="choice_1_112_1">
        <label for="choice_1_112_1" id="label_1_112_1">eTrade Package</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @wahwahwah thanks for editing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with a simple JS script implementing to trigger button click and add product directly to the cart

```js
 jQuery("#btn_349").on("click", function(){
    jQuery("#choice_1_112_0").prop("checked", true);
    jQuery("#btn_350").text("Select");
    jQuery("#btn_349").text("Selected");
    jQuery(this).css("background-color", "#c11c2d");
    jQuery("#btn_350").css("background-color", "#333335");
   
});


jQuery("#btn_350").on("click", function(){
    jQuery("#choice_1_112_1").prop("checked", true);
    jQuery("#btn_349").text("Select");
    jQuery("#btn_350").text("Selected");
    jQuery(this).css("background-color", "#c11c2d");
     jQuery("#btn_349").css("background-color", "#333335");
   
});
```